# Writing to event logger exception c#

Tags: c#, logging, event-viewer

I'm trying to write to the event viewer in Windows. But I keep getting an exception when I execute the `WriteEntry()` function. It's saying: `cannot open log for 'source' you may not have write access`. As far as I know I'm an administrator here and i'm writing to the ULS logs just fine, just not to the event viewer.

```
public MethodLogger(MethodBase methodBase)
    {
        if (methodBase == null) return;
        _methodName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.{1}", methodBase.DeclaringType, methodBase.Name);
        LoggingService.LogMessage(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Entering {0}", _methodName));
    } 

 public static void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsCategory category = Current.Areas[_diagnosticName].Categories[LoggingService.Information];
        Current.WriteTrace(ServiceId, category, TraceSeverity.Verbose, message);
        //Log.Information(message);
    }

public void Information(string text)
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Source"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("Source", "Source");
        }


        EventLog.WriteEntry("Source", text, EventLogEntryType.Information);


    }
```

The last WriteEntry is where the exception is being thrown. In event viewer a folder exists called "Source" so that if statement beforehand is evaluating to `true` which is fine.

Why can't I be writing to this event viewer?

Comment: Is the application running under your user?

Comment: Try run as administrator.

Comment: Running Event Viewer as Administrator? I have, still nothing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your application doesn't have appropriate permissions?

Try the steps outlined here (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028427) and see if it helps you.

Comment: It might be a permission thing, but I don't want to do any registry changes as this will not work when I deploy it to production environment.